# Why does "Euphoria" avoid specifying its setting as California?

Tags: euphoria

The filming location of "Euphoria" is California, and the environmental cues, such as the absence of snow in the New Year's episode and the visible mountains, strongly suggest a Californian setting. Despite these indicators, the show refrains from outright stating that it's set in California. This is further highlighted by the use of custom license plates, a deliberate choice that seems to avoid associating the show with a specific geographical area. Why is there an intentional ambiguity about the show's setting?

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-do-TV-shows-have-fictional-cities

Comment: "*...not giving the audience a specific, named place for the events and storylines we get ... allows for and creates a sense that everything that happens in Euphoria could take place in any city or suburb where teenagers reside. ... the events unfolding on screen are universal and therefore a specific location is not necessary for young people to be able to relate or feel like they have experienced at some point. A generic, unspecified setting with a storyline featuring universal themes experienced by teens alike can then be seen as a good choice when wanting to reach a broader audience.*

Comment: That's from a scholarly work called *"Teen identities in Euphoria and Sex Education"*